# Why do I get an unexpected output error when calling register_activation_hook?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I am coding a plugin for WordPress.  When I’m using the function `register_activation_hook`, I get the following error:

```
The plugin generated 28 characters of unexpected output during activation.
If you notice "headers already sent" messages, 
problems with syndication feeds or other issues,
try deactivating or removing this plugin.
```

Relevant code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function(){
echo "<script>alert('ok')</script>";
});
```

Comment: Your activation hook is outputting a <script> tag; but I assume WordPress is expecting HTML headers only to be output at that point - your echo is 28 characters long. Maybe if you used `return` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is probably being called before headers are sent. If **any** output is generated before issuing `header()`, then PHP/Wordpress usually complains.

Try this instead:

```
function my_activation_func() {    
    echo "<script>alert('ok')</script>";
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation_func' );
```

Read the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).

Comment: i tried it its still the same problem